# Как вставить кнопку для изменения положения камеры (3D/2D) в JS API 3.0 Яндек.Карты?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отобразить данную кнопку со всем необходимым функционалом, который она несет? Смотрел документацию, там нашел про вставку кнопок зума и геолокации, но нигде не смог найти информацию про эту кнопку. Хотя на странице яндекс карт она есть - https://yandex.ru/maps/

На странице с демкой есть похожий функционал этой кнопки - https://codesandbox.io/embed/5mdvkd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&initialpath=vanilla.html&module=vanilla.html&moduleview=1 - кнопки "Tilt the camera" и "Rase the camera".

Ниже часть моего кода:

```
 // ожидание загрузки модулей
await ymaps3.ready;

const {
  YMap,
  YMapDefaultSchemeLayer,
  YMapControls,
  YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer,
  YMapMarker,
} = ymaps3;

// Импорт модулей для элементов управления на карте
const { YMapZoomControl, YMapGeolocationControl } = await ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-controls@0.0.1');

// Создание объекта карты
const map = new YMap(document.querySelector('#map'), {
  location: {
    center: [40.434168, 56.151151],
    zoom: 14,
  },
});

// добавление кнопки зума и геолокации
const controls = new YMapControls({ position: 'right', orientation: 'vertical' });
controls.addChild(new YMapZoomControl({}));
controls.addChild(new YMapGeolocationControl({}));
map.addChild(controls);
```

Comment: Если что-то есть в Картах, это не значит, что такое доступно всем и содержится в самом API. Если Яндекс это не документирует, значит возможности или нет, или она закрыта. В этом случае диск с вращением и наклоном вам придётся реализовать самостоятельно — внешний вид, алгоритм вращения.

Comment: @YaCor' спасибо, да вы правы, как раз получил похожий ответ от поддержки.

Answer (score 2):

Получил ответ от поддержки:

*В JS API 3.0 появилась возможность изменять положение камеры, реализовать это можно с помощью [поведений](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/dg/concepts/events#behavior-type), таких как:*

- *mouseTilt - Наклон карты мышью;*
- *mouseRotate - Поворот карты мышью;*
- *И т.д.*

*Увидеть как это реализовано можно в одном из наших примеров в [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/5mdvkd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&initialpath=vanilla.html&module=vanilla.html&moduleview=1).*

*Просто вставить именно такую кнопку, которую вы привели в пример, не получиться, только если сверстать такого вида кнопки и задать на них события которые я описал выше.*